# React - Sort object entries by key in a specific order

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object

```
{
   "undefined": 10, 
   "women": 5,
   "men": 3,
}
```

And I need to sort it, so it looks like

```
{
   "men": 3,
   "women": 5,
   "undefined": 10, 
}
```

How can I do it?

I have tried to sort it like that, but it works alphabetically.

```js
const object = {
  "undefined": 10,
  "women": 3,
  "men": 6
}

const entries = Object.entries(object).sort();

const sortedObject =  Object.fromEntries(entries);

console.log(sortedObject);

/*
   Expected result: 
   
   {
     "men": 6,
     "women": 3,
     "undefined": 10
   }
*/
```

This is what I am trying to do:

*statsParser.js*

```
import { t } from "i18n";

export default (genders) => {
  if (!genders) return;

  const entries = Object.entries(genders).sort(([, a], [, b]) => b - a); // What if I want to order the map so it looks like { men: x, women: y, undefined: z } instead of by value in desc order?

  const translatedEntries = entries.map((entry) => [
    t(`content.stats.genders.${entry[0].toLowerCase()}`),
    entry[1],
  ]);

  const translatedGenders = Object.fromEntries(translatedEntries);

  return translatedGenders;
};
```

Comment: In JavaScript the object keys didn’t  have a particular order. It seems to depend on the JS engine

Comment: Raul, this isn't possible. What are you really trying to do? It may just mean a change to your data structure.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Would an array suit you? Why would you need such ordering? Looks like you're trying to do something wrong here

Comment: Also I don’t think a key can be called undefined?

Comment: I am adding the stats of something in my db. As I have 3 genders: "Man", "Woman", and "Undefined", I am saving a counter in a map Key (gender) - Value (counter).

Comment: @evolutionxbox yeah you are right, but it is in my use case domain,  I am storing it as a string in my db, so it is not undefined, it is "undefined"

Comment: As in the frontend I need to translate the map keys (i18n.js), I just map into that object entries, in order to translate them.

Comment: BTW, I am thinking about sorting by the value instead of the key (in a particular order, which seems to be impossible).

Comment: Why do you need to order it at all?

Comment: @evolutionxbox just because of look-and-feel purposes. I am implementing a pull to refresh in the screen that renders the stats, and if the user does it multiple times, data will be render "unsorted". I don't wanna do the sorting inside the UI component, just because of performance (re-renderizations etc). It seems more clean to me to do that in my api method, in some kind of parser.

Comment: I will share my full parser code in the question, so you can see what I am trying to do

Comment: Doing multiple hits to a server will be more expensive in terms of performance than just sorting the state and rerendering.

Answer (score 0):

To sort json object using `key` is easy as below:

```
const unordered = {
   "undefined": 10, 
   "women": 5,
   "men": 3,
}    
const ordered = Object.keys(unordered).sort().reduce(
  (obj, key) => { 
    obj[key] = unordered[key]; 
    return obj;
  }, 
  {}
);

console.log(JSON.stringify(ordered));
```

To sort json object using `value`, you need convert your object into array using `Object.entries`. Then you sort that array using value and prepare string using map function and finally parse it into json.

```
const unordered = {
   "undefined": 10, 
   "women": 5,
   "men": 3,
}
const arrOfArrays = Object.entries(unordered);

const ordered = arrOfArrays.sort((a, b) => {
    const aVal = Object.values(a)[1];
    const bVal = Object.values(b)[1];
    return aVal - bVal;
  }); 

var jsonString = "{";
ordered.map(obj => {
  var json = { ...obj };
  jsonString += `"${json[0]}":"${json[1]}",`;
});
jsonString = jsonString.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
jsonString += "}";

console.log(JSON.parse(jsonString));
```

Comment: I’m pretty sure that JSON doesn’t have nor does it  respect object key order.